# Make Specific TinyMCE TextArea ReadOnly or Design

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

I have a Razor page that has multiple `textarea` fields. Before I was using TinyMCE, I used the following Javascript to enable/disable a specific `textarea` based on the selection of a checkbox.

```
 if ('@Model.IssueData.rootCauseIdentified' == "true") {
      document.getElementById("rootcause").disabled = false;
      document.getElementById("rootcause").style.backgroundColor = "white";
 } else {
      document.getElementById("rootcause").style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";
 }
```

I've now converted the `textarea` to use TinyMCE. How do I target this one `textarea` to enable/disable it? I've already created 2 init sections where 1 targets all but the single `textarea` I want to change.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '.tinymce1',
    menubar: false,
    plugins: [
        'advlist autolink lists link charmap',
        'searchreplace',
        'insertdatetime table paste wordcount'
    ],
    toolbar: 'undo redo | ' +
        'bold italic underline forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
        'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent |link charmap ' +
        'removeformat'
});
tinymce.init({
    selector: '.toenabledisable',
    menubar: false,
    plugins: [
        'advlist autolink lists link charmap',
        'searchreplace',
        'insertdatetime table paste wordcount'
    ],
    toolbar: 'undo redo | ' +
        'bold italic underline forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
        'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent |link charmap ' +
        'removeformat'
});
```

I've come across the following code but don't know how to modify it to target only the `textarea` I want (specifically the `tinymce.activeEditor.mode.set` section).

```
function toggleEditorMode(mode) {
if (mode) {
  tinymce.activeEditor.mode.set("design");
} else {
  tinymce.activeEditor.mode.set("readonly");
}
```

EDIT: Solution
Based on the comment below I was able to come up with the following code which works for me:

```
if (elementid == "rootcause") {              
    if (element.checked) {
        tinymce.get('rootcause').mode.set("design");
    } else {                   
        tinymce.get('rootcause').mode.set("readonly");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to target a specific editor instance you can use the `tinymce.get()` API to target one by the **ID** of the underlying textarea:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/root_tinymce/#get

You can also get an array of all the editors with `tinymce.editors`.  This will provide you an array of all the instantiated editors on the page.

Comment: Here is an example using the `tinymce.editors` approach: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/33haab

Comment: @MichaelFromin Thanks. Your comment got me to the solution.

Comment: @TinyLincoln - Thank you for the example. While I already had selection code, I plan on keeping your example bookmarked for future use.